# How to join on subqueries using ARel?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel

I have a few massive SQL request involving join across various models in my rails application.
A single request can involve 6 to 10 tables.

To run the request faster I want to use sub-queries in the joins (that way I can filter these tables before the join and reduce the columns to the ones I need). I'm trying to achieve this using ARel.

I thought I found the solution to my problem there: [How to do joins on subqueries in AREL within Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528750/how-to-do-joins-on-subqueries-in-arel-within-rails), 
but things must have changed because I get `undefined method '[]' for Arel::SelectManager`.

Does anybody have any idea how to achieve this (without using strings) ?

Comment: Can you show the query you are attempting?

Comment: Well to simplify it to the extreme level:
SELECT A.* INNER JOIN (SELECT B.a_id FROM B WHERE B.c > 4) B ON A.id = B.a_id

Comment: Can you should the Ruby code you are attempting for the query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pierre, I thought a better solution could be the following (inspiration from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenharman/4589186)):

```
a = A.arel_table  
b = B.arel_table

subquery = b.project(b[:a_id].as('A_id')).where{c > 4}  
subquery = subquery.as('intm_table')  
query = A.join(subquery).on(subquery[:A_id].eq(a[:id]))
```

No particular reason for naming the alias as "intm_table", I just thought it would be less confusing.

Comment: `A.join(subquery).on(subquery[:A_id].eq(a[:id]))` return error `NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for #<Class`

Answer (score 6):

OK so my main problem was that you can't join a Arel::SelectManager ... BUT you can join a table aliasing.
So to generate the request in my comment above:

```
a = A.arel_table
b = B.arel_table

subquery = B.select(:a_id).where{c > 4}
query = A.join(subquery.as('B')).on(b[:a_id].eq(a[:id])
query.to_sql # SELECT A.* INNER JOIN (SELECT B.a_id FROM B WHERE B.c > 4) B ON A.id = B.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this, and was helped by the other answers, but there are some error in both, e.g. `A.join(...` should be `a.join(...`.
And I also missed how to build an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Here is how to build an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, in Rails 4

```
a = A.arel_table
b = B.arel_table

subsel = B.select(b[:a_id]).where(b[:c].gt('4')).as('sub_select')
joins  = a.join(subsel).on(subsel[:a_id].eq(a[:id])).join_sources
rel    = A.joins(joins)
rel.to_sql
#=> "SELECT `a`.* FROM `a` INNER JOIN (SELECT `b`.`a_id` FROM `b` WHERE (`b`.`c` > 4)) sub_select ON sub_select.`a_id` = `a`.`id`"
```